# Can Jenkins show the status of all tests across multiple modules at one go?

Tags: jenkins, junit, jenkins-plugins

I have a multi-component Java based application that is using Jenkins for CI. Each component has unit tests (Junit) and integration tests (Concordion). At the moment, when I open Jenkins I see each project individually. Once I am inside a particular project I can see how many tests are failing, how many passing and what has been the trend.

I was wondering if there was any plugin that can tell me - right at the first page when Jenkins opens up - what is the total (cumulative of all projects on Jenkins) tests that are passing and how many are not?

To give more context - I have multiple people working on multiple modules, changes to one module have the potential to break tests for other modules. For a person checking in their code, it is impractical to go into multiple components and make sure that their changes have not broken anything. It would be much easier if I knew that there were total 1000 passing tests before I checked in my changes and now there are 998. I know there are 2 tests broken and I can then drill into different modules to see where the culprits are.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to publish test results from multiple modules on Jenkins. Try one of these two plugins [Multi Module Tests Publisher](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multi+Module+Tests+Publisher) and [Dashboard View](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Dashboard+View).

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't tried it personally, but by the looks of it maybe the [Dashboard View](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Dashboard+View) plugin does what you're looking for?